# How would I turn a array in to ol in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Right now I have a array that has a parent_id & I think I need to use recursion to accomplish what I would like to do

```
array
  0 => 
    object(Menu)[56]
      public 'attributes' => 
        array
          'id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_name' => string 'home' (length=4)
          'menu_url' => string 'test' (length=4)
          'parent_id' => string '0' (length=1)
          'position' => string '0' (length=1)
          'group_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_items' => null
      public 'original' => 
        array
          'id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_name' => string 'home' (length=4)
          'menu_url' => string 'test' (length=4)
          'parent_id' => string '0' (length=1)
          'position' => string '0' (length=1)
          'group_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_items' => null
      public 'relationships' => 
        array
          empty
      public 'exists' => boolean true
      public 'includes' => 
        array
          empty
  1 => 
    object(Menu)[60]
      public 'attributes' => 
        array
          'id' => string '2' (length=1)
          'menu_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_name' => string 'Contact Us' (length=10)
          'menu_url' => string 'contact' (length=7)
          'parent_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'position' => string '0' (length=1)
          'group_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_items' => null
      public 'original' => 
        array
          'id' => string '2' (length=1)
          'menu_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_name' => string 'Contact Us' (length=10)
          'menu_url' => string 'contact' (length=7)
          'parent_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'position' => string '0' (length=1)
          'group_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_items' => null
      public 'relationships' => 
        array
          empty
      public 'exists' => boolean true
      public 'includes' => 
        array
          empty
  2 => 
    object(Menu)[61]
      public 'attributes' => 
        array
          'id' => string '3' (length=1)
          'menu_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_name' => string 'Privacy Docs' (length=12)
          'menu_url' => string 'privacy' (length=7)
          'parent_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'position' => string '0' (length=1)
          'group_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_items' => null
      public 'original' => 
        array
          'id' => string '3' (length=1)
          'menu_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_name' => string 'Privacy Docs' (length=12)
          'menu_url' => string 'privacy' (length=7)
          'parent_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'position' => string '0' (length=1)
          'group_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_items' => null
      public 'relationships' => 
        array
          empty
      public 'exists' => boolean true
      public 'includes' => 
        array
          empty

array
  0 => 
    object(Menu)[56]
      public 'attributes' => 
        array
          'id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_name' => string 'home' (length=4)
          'menu_url' => string 'test' (length=4)
          'parent_id' => string '0' (length=1)
          'position' => string '0' (length=1)
          'group_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_items' => null
      public 'original' => 
        array
          'id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_name' => string 'home' (length=4)
          'menu_url' => string 'test' (length=4)
          'parent_id' => string '0' (length=1)
          'position' => string '0' (length=1)
          'group_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_items' => null
      public 'relationships' => 
        array
          empty
      public 'exists' => boolean true
      public 'includes' => 
        array
          empty
  1 => 
    object(Menu)[60]
      public 'attributes' => 
        array
          'id' => string '2' (length=1)
          'menu_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_name' => string 'Contact Us' (length=10)
          'menu_url' => string 'contact' (length=7)
          'parent_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'position' => string '0' (length=1)
          'group_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_items' => null
      public 'original' => 
        array
          'id' => string '2' (length=1)
          'menu_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_name' => string 'Contact Us' (length=10)
          'menu_url' => string 'contact' (length=7)
          'parent_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'position' => string '0' (length=1)
          'group_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_items' => null
      public 'relationships' => 
        array
          empty
      public 'exists' => boolean true
      public 'includes' => 
        array
          empty
  2 => 
    object(Menu)[61]
      public 'attributes' => 
        array
          'id' => string '3' (length=1)
          'menu_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_name' => string 'Privacy Docs' (length=12)
          'menu_url' => string 'privacy' (length=7)
          'parent_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'position' => string '0' (length=1)
          'group_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_items' => null
      public 'original' => 
        array
          'id' => string '3' (length=1)
          'menu_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_name' => string 'Privacy Docs' (length=12)
          'menu_url' => string 'privacy' (length=7)
          'parent_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'position' => string '0' (length=1)
          'group_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_items' => null
      public 'relationships' => 
        array
          empty
      public 'exists' => boolean true
      public 'includes' => 
        array
          empty

array
  0 => 
    object(Menu)[56]
      public 'attributes' => 
        array
          'id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_name' => string 'home' (length=4)
          'menu_url' => string 'test' (length=4)
          'parent_id' => string '0' (length=1)
          'position' => string '0' (length=1)
          'group_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_items' => null
      public 'original' => 
        array
          'id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_name' => string 'home' (length=4)
          'menu_url' => string 'test' (length=4)
          'parent_id' => string '0' (length=1)
          'position' => string '0' (length=1)
          'group_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_items' => null
      public 'relationships' => 
        array
          empty
      public 'exists' => boolean true
      public 'includes' => 
        array
          empty
  1 => 
    object(Menu)[60]
      public 'attributes' => 
        array
          'id' => string '2' (length=1)
          'menu_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_name' => string 'Contact Us' (length=10)
          'menu_url' => string 'contact' (length=7)
          'parent_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'position' => string '0' (length=1)
          'group_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_items' => null
      public 'original' => 
        array
          'id' => string '2' (length=1)
          'menu_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_name' => string 'Contact Us' (length=10)
          'menu_url' => string 'contact' (length=7)
          'parent_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'position' => string '0' (length=1)
          'group_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_items' => null
      public 'relationships' => 
        array
          empty
      public 'exists' => boolean true
      public 'includes' => 
        array
          empty
  2 => 
    object(Menu)[61]
      public 'attributes' => 
        array
          'id' => string '3' (length=1)
          'menu_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_name' => string 'Privacy Docs' (length=12)
          'menu_url' => string 'privacy' (length=7)
          'parent_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'position' => string '0' (length=1)
          'group_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_items' => null
      public 'original' => 
        array
          'id' => string '3' (length=1)
          'menu_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_name' => string 'Privacy Docs' (length=12)
          'menu_url' => string 'privacy' (length=7)
          'parent_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'position' => string '0' (length=1)
          'group_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_items' => null
      public 'relationships' => 
        array
          empty
      public 'exists' => boolean true
      public 'includes' => 
        array
          empty

array
  0 => 
    object(Menu)[56]
      public 'attributes' => 
        array
          'id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_name' => string 'home' (length=4)
          'menu_url' => string 'test' (length=4)
          'parent_id' => string '0' (length=1)
          'position' => string '0' (length=1)
          'group_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_items' => null
      public 'original' => 
        array
          'id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_name' => string 'home' (length=4)
          'menu_url' => string 'test' (length=4)
          'parent_id' => string '0' (length=1)
          'position' => string '0' (length=1)
          'group_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_items' => null
      public 'relationships' => 
        array
          empty
      public 'exists' => boolean true
      public 'includes' => 
        array
          empty
  1 => 
    object(Menu)[60]
      public 'attributes' => 
        array
          'id' => string '2' (length=1)
          'menu_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_name' => string 'Contact Us' (length=10)
          'menu_url' => string 'contact' (length=7)
          'parent_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'position' => string '0' (length=1)
          'group_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_items' => null
      public 'original' => 
        array
          'id' => string '2' (length=1)
          'menu_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_name' => string 'Contact Us' (length=10)
          'menu_url' => string 'contact' (length=7)
          'parent_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'position' => string '0' (length=1)
          'group_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_items' => null
      public 'relationships' => 
        array
          empty
      public 'exists' => boolean true
      public 'includes' => 
        array
          empty
  2 => 
    object(Menu)[61]
      public 'attributes' => 
        array
          'id' => string '3' (length=1)
          'menu_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_name' => string 'Privacy Docs' (length=12)
          'menu_url' => string 'privacy' (length=7)
          'parent_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'position' => string '0' (length=1)
          'group_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_items' => null
      public 'original' => 
        array
          'id' => string '3' (length=1)
          'menu_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_name' => string 'Privacy Docs' (length=12)
          'menu_url' => string 'privacy' (length=7)
          'parent_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'position' => string '0' (length=1)
          'group_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'menu_items' => null
      public 'relationships' => 
        array
          empty
      public 'exists' => boolean true
      public 'includes' => 
        array
          empty
```

Right now I have a function in a class called menuHelper

```
public static function make(array $array, $no = 0) {
        var_dump($array);
        $child = self::hasChildren($array, $no);
        if (empty($child))
            return "";
        $content = "<li>\n";
        foreach ($child as $value) {
            $content = sprintf("\t<li><div>%s</div>" . self::make($array, $value->id) . "</li>\n", $value->menu_name);
            //$content .= self::make($array, $value->id);
        }
        $content .= "</li>\n";
        //return $content;
        return($content == '' ? '' : "<ol>" . $content . "</ol>");
    }
public static function hasChildren($array, $id) {
        return array_filter($array, function ($var) use($id) {
                    return $var->parent_id == $id;
                });
    }
```

That I want this to output this

```
<ol class="sortable">
    <li>
        <div>parent</div>
        <ol>
            <div>Sub</div>
            <ol>
                <div>Sub 2</div>
            </ol>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>parent 2</div>
        <ol>
            <div>Sub</div>
            <ol>
                <div>Sub 2</div>
            </ol>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

But that does not keep outputing parents it instead outputs 1 parent and then its children. Then it quits outputing even if theres another parent so I guess I have something wrong?

Comment: This is not about storing data if you would look at the question.

Comment: Fascinating, no idea how these actions got pinned to this question as both were targeting someone else.

Comment: Post your array too. That will make half way done

Comment: Ok I will in just a second

Comment: I do not know laravel. I thought You want to make those list from a php array where Those data will be located. I do not know how to get data from it.

Comment: Well if you know how to do it in regular php I can translate it into laravel thanks for the help

Comment: How are you actually loading data into `$array`?

Comment: Well I'm using laravel but the laravel way would be Menu::where('is_menu_parent', '=', '0')->get() But translate that into regular php query mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menus WHERE is_menu_parent='0'");

Comment: This question is about how to load hierarchical data and properly present it in Laravel. This is about dealing with the ORM and not a data structure.

Comment: Yes you got it Robert nobody else did guess I was not getting it across to them maybe? This site never helps me when I ask questions they always don't read and mark stuff as duplicates the admin of this site needs to give less power to people that don't read. Oh well I figured it out :)

Comment: If you're going for multiple levels look at nested sets. Doing it with recursion is messy. Also, if you solved it, post your solution and then mark it as the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Could you explain why nested set is so much better. I would open a question about it but. it would just get flagged or marked as duplicate. For this site to be about questions it sure looks like this site doesn't care to help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really rough answer because your question is vague and missing details.

What you need is to store your main menu items in an array and then loop through them to draw the main menu. Then, as you loop through each main menu item, lookup/load any child menu items that parent might have. If there are child menu items - draw the child menu. easy peasy.

```
<ol class="sortable">
<?php
$main_menu_items = array( $first_menu_item, $second_menu_item );
foreach($main_menu_items as $menu_item)
{
    ?>
    <li>
    <div><?=$menu_item['menu_name']?></div>
    <?php
    $child_menu_items = get_child_menu_items($menu_item['menu_id']);
    if( count($child_menu_items) > 0 )
    {
        ?>
        <ol>
        <?php
        foreach($child_menu_items as $child_item)
        {
            ?>
            <li><div><?=$menu_item['menu_name']?></div></li>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
        </ol>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    </li>
    <?php
}
?>
</ol>
```

Comment: Sorry that my question is vague I don't normally ask questions but this really stumped me. This child menu foreach loop would that keep creating child menu as they go along? https://gist.github.com/dragonfire1119/a9784a2821836411d634

Comment: I guess I can put this in a function and keep calling the function and checking if it has anymore children?

Comment: In order to handle an array with depth of 3, you'd just have to add one more foreach loop inside the second foreach loop. If you want to be able handle arrays any deeper than that, you'll need to rewrite the function to be recursive - which is more complicated. Take a look at Wordpress's source code to see how they do it. 

In order to use this code, you'd have to create a function to find the children of the current menu being looped through.

Comment: Ya there doing it much different there putting <li></li> and manipulating the position in jquery/css to make it look like its nesting. But I'm using a different jquery plugin then what there using so its not that easy for me.